# Can a transaction be rolled back after it's committed and connection is closed?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008, transactions

Can a transaction be rolled back after it's committed and connection is closed?

```
    finally
    {
        // Commit the transaction.
        sqlTran.Commit();

        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
```

I would like to give the user an option of *Opps! roll it back*. So if it's commited can it be rolled back?

Comment: You're aware of what the word "commit" means, right?  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/commit  :P  Committing a transaction says "this is what i want done.  Yes, i'm sure...do it!"  You don't get to up and change your mind later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A committed transaction can never be rolled back if you want your transaction to be persistent after a commit.

Are you looking for [savepoints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-savepoint.html)?

Comment: related: [Is it possible to retrieve the current SQL Transaction in c# when connection was closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469791/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-current-sql-transaction-in-c-sharp-when-connectio#6469963)

Answer (score 3):

Well if it committed, it is committed. No rolling back.
If you want to be dumb-user-proof, set up a timer and commit only after a delay, giving the user the option to rollback for a while.

Comment: There could be some issues with this solution.  For example, what happens if your systems lose power before the timer fires?  The user will assume the transaction was committed, when in fact it will be rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

simply no. you cannot :)

The Commit method is equivalent to the Transact-SQL COMMIT TRANSACTION statement. You cannot roll back a transaction once it has been committed, because all modifications have become a permanent part of the database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you put your 'oops!' case at the appropriate point you should be able to do what you need.

Also, take a look at [nested transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336.aspx), maybe that'll fit your scenario even better.

Finally as Tobias points out there are [save points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx).