# Is it possible to retrieve the current SQL Transaction in c# when connection was closed?

Tags: c#, sql, transactions, database-connection

Is it possible to retrieve the current SQL Transaction in c# when connection was closed?

```
sqlTransaction.Save("savePoint"); 
sqlConnection.Close()              // im purposely closing it to test 

if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Close)
{
    sqlConnection.Open():

   // is it possible to resume the sql transaction when I re-open    
   // the sql connection? how? 
}
```

Comment: Try to and see.  What happens if you try to use the transaction?  Does it throw an exception?

Comment: Well, I should have probably mentioned above that if I try to re-use the transaction. The connection becomes null therefore it will throw an error. Also, if I try to re-assign the connection using BeginConnection() then the save point for the transaction can't be used anymore.

Comment: Don't think you can -- any context you can provide around why you would want to that?  Generally, a transaction and connection are tightly bound, so curious about what your use case is.  Maybe there's something else that can be done to achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SqlTransaction.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.save%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) does not 'save' the transaction, instead it creates a transaction savepoint, which is something completely different:

> Creates a savepoint in the transaction
>   that can be used to roll back a part
>   of the transaction, and specifies the
>   savepoint name.

A savepoint can be used *before* the transaction is committed to partially rollback some of the work done by the transaction. A typical example would be an attempt to do an update that *may* fail, so you create a savepoint before doing the update and in case of failure you rollback to the savepoint, thus preserving all the work done prior to the savepoint.

See [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/) for an example of how to use savepoints.

Now back to your question, is there a way for a connection to start a connection, close, and when re-open, pick up the *same* transaction? Technically there is, by using the (now deprecated) [`sp_getbindtoken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180061.aspx) and [`sp_bindsession`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174403.aspx). But this is just a curiosity, there is absolutely no valid scenario for you to attempt to 'reuse' a transaction across two different sessions (two re-opens of a connection).

Answer (score 5):

No, SQL Server will rollback any uncommitted transactions when the connection is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a misunderstanding of a database transaction. Transactions are all-or-nothing conversations with the database. If you close the line of communication with the database by closing the connection, the conversation is over and the changes are not committed (the "nothing" part of "all-or-nothing").

Answer (score -1):

No, I don't think you can do this.